# How to store Profile Pictures in NodeJS & Mongodb?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Let's say that I am creating a website where users can register, login, and see each other's profile.

I have already created the Register, Login and seeing other's profile's functionality, however I don't know how I could possibly add profile pictures unique to each user.

This is how I'm currently saving the user data.

```
mongoose.Schema({
 username: {
   type: String,
   unique: true,
   required: true
 },
 email: {
   type: String,
   lowercase: true,
   unique: true,
   required: true
 },
 password: {
   type: String,
   required: true
 }
});
```

Where should I save these images? Is it even possible to save .png files in a mongodb?

When I wanted to see the images in my HTML / View Engine, would I simply use something like:

```
<img src="<%= user.image %>">
```

And then make the actual image be saved somewhere in my files?

Comment: Why you want to use MongoDB as object-storage instead of (maybe) Amazon S3? There is some specific reason?

Comment: Why would you want to send binary data to a template to render is the bigger question. Your templates should only be concerned with URL's that point to an image location endpoint, whether that endpoint resolves to retrieving data from MongoDB or S3 or filesystem should really have nothing to do with the template render itself. Let the browser fetch the image. Don't re-invent the wheel when the wheel works just fine.

Comment: Actually.. I'm not sure what the best way to do this is. This is my first time doing something even close to this with Javascript. In PHP it was something as simple as https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jvnRFsFwiT8  but I'm just not sure how to do that in Node...

Comment: I suggest saving the link in the user_image using the type String. then store the image it self on your server or s3 (Amazon service).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are three way to achieve your goal.

1. **Save the Field directly in MongoDB (document)**
2. **Save the Field directly in MongoDB (GridFS)**
3. **Upload to AmazonS3 and save the ID directly in MongoDB (document)**

1) Only in few case where honestly you have not so much to store (I never use this scenario in production, but many time in testing). So I don't recommend you to move in this direction.

2) It's ideal for large images and where you need to add some "logic". For example i used in the past GridFS to have the "full image" and a list of images resized (user1_120_90.png, user1_320_240.png) in the same place and access to them very quickly since you have a very low latency. Even more i can add some "custom field" to the stored object and then made a query to obtain exactly what i need without deal with Amazon-S3.

3) Very scalable solution that offer you some advantage (S3 is less expansive then GridFS in terms of cost because GridFS is charged you as "database space" where Amazon-S3 is charged to you as "just object-storage". In the past a lot of project was based there. S3 came with a NPM module that is easy to use and manage.

For your scenario I can suggest you to separate the Database from the Object-Storage. Then move your files on Amazon, Azure, Google. If then you have to deal with very low-latency scenario, maybe you can consider GridFS (in my case the deal was to manage 400Mln 3D images with a lot of geometry associated to them and stored inside GridFS as metadata field).

Reference GridFS:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/

Good Luck!

Comment: Are there any other alternatives to s3 that you would suggest especially free tier? I know s3 is also free for 1 year.